# Communication between two Cassandra nodes

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Assume two Cassandra nodes running on hosts `A` and `B` respectively. Which TCP and/or UDP ports needs to be open between hosts `A` and `B` for Cassandra to operate properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how you have configured storage-conf.xml on your two nodes.

Hint. take a look at `<StoragePort>7000</StoragePort>` in storage-conf.xml. 
(TCP port 7000 is the standard/default port used by Cassandra for internal communication, i.e. address to bind to and tell other nodes to connect to).

UDP port (7001 default) was previous used for gossip, was removed in 0.6.0.